# How do i open a new terminal in python and control it?

Tags: python, console, cross-platform, window-management

how do I, crossplatform, open a new terminal window and control it? I want to be able to send text to the terminal, and recieve keyboard inputs, without needing to run in console mode, as this program will be running as a pyw and not py.

I havent tried anything yet, as i still am thinking about how i want to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

The `subprocess` module can help you there. Something like that:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def open_terminal():
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        subprocess.Popen('start', shell=True)
    elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
        subprocess.Popen('open -a Terminal .', shell=True)
    else:
        try:
            subprocess.Popen('gnome-terminal', shell=True)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            try:
                subprocess.Popen('xterm', shell=True)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Unsupported platform")
                sys.exit(1)

open_terminal()
```

Comment: this just opens a shell... I wanted something that would allow me to control it

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use [os module](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-system-command-os-subprocess-call). With it, you can easily execute terminal commands.
To get keyboard input there is various module you can use, like [keyboard module](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-system-command-os-subprocess-call):

```py
import keyboard

while True:  # Loop to capture keys continuously
    event = keyboard.read_event()  # Capture a keyboard event

    if event.name == 'q' and event.event_type == 'down':
        print("Q key was pressed.")
        break
    elif event.event_type == 'down':
        print(f"{event.name} key was pressed")
```

Comment: wouldn't this capture keypresses even if the window isn't focused?

Comment: @nate_4000 No unfortunately I don't think so

Comment: thats good because most of the time i use the keyboard library it captures all keypresses which is bad